# Get value from entrySet of HashMap and send it to new activity

Tags: android, android-intent, hashmap, google-maps-markers

I have markers on my map and I have used a HashMap to store extra data which is numbers. I have used the markers as keys and the values as numbers. An example is like below:

```
HashMap<Marker, String> hash = new HashMap<Marker, String>();

Marker marker1 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
        new LatLng(randomLocation1[0], randomLocation1[1]))
                .title("Waiyaki")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)
));
hash.put(marker1,"24354345");

Marker marker2 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
        new LatLng(randomLocation2[0], randomLocation2[1]))
                .title("Parklands")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)
));
hash.put(marker2,"34354353");
```

I would like when the user clicks on the infowindow of a particular marker, the values in the entrySet of that marker to be sent to a new activity. The sample code of what I have done is below:

```
googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0)            
        for (Entry<Marker, String> entry : hash.entrySet()) {
            String value = entry.getValue();
            Intent I = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
            I.putExtra(value, isFinishing());
            startActivity(I);
        }

    }
});
```

There is something wrong with the code above but I do not know what exactly. Some help please...and also a sample code as to how I will send the value to a new activity.

Comment: It's not clear which data you want to send to new activity. putExtra() needs key and value. In the code above you are sending a number associated with a marker as a key and result of some function as a value.

Comment: I want to send the number associated with the marker to new activity

Answer (score 0):

To send a number associated with the marker replace the code

```
I.putExtra(value, isFinishing());
```

with

```
I.putExtra("markerNumber", value);
```

Within the MainActivity use the following code to get the value:

```
String markerNumber = getIntent().getExtras().getString("markerNumber");
```